# Back navigation does not stop youtube video in WebBrowser

Tags: codenameone

I have a form which plays youtube video. When I go back with the back navigation the youtube video still plays in the background. Doesn't back navigation totally destroy the current form?
The issue forced me to add an actionlistener to the back button like this

```
@Override
protected void onYoutubeIframe_TopBackButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
    findYoutubeWebBrowser(c).removeAll();
}
```

.stop() and removeAll() does nothing. The video still streams in the bakground

Answer (score 2):

Try `browserComponent.destroy()` which should clean up properly